# Setting logging for rosserial app from ros command line

Tags: rosserial

My arduino code is using rosserial's loginfo and friends for logging output. I want to control the level from the ROS command line and have it apply dynamically to what is happening on the arduino. What "node name" do I use?

The documentation for rosconsole says that I can set the logging level with a command like:

```
rosconsole set /rosserial_lino rosout debug
```

Where /rosserial_lino is the node name. I tried various node names but nothing seems to work.